# AzureDevOps - Creating generic team

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

In Azure DevOps, a default project team will be created when we create a new project in a given collection. We can then add/invite members to this team and assign their level of permission. So far it is clear to me.

However, in my case, I have multiple projects and in each project there shall mostly be static set of developers.

**Question**:

a) Is it possible to create a default team at collection level (rather than project level) and assign users to it?

b) If srl (a) is possible, how would we instruct Azure DevOps to assign this default team as project team for all projects those shall be created under project collection ?

**For example**: Within a collection called *Services*, I have projects with users like below

*Service A* will have developers x, y

*Service B* will have developers x, y

*Service C* will have developers x, y, z

I prefer a default team with users (x, y); and this team will be assigned to all projects those are created under Services collection.

Exception: Service C has an extra developer Z. This is fine since we can visit project and explicitly add this developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a) Is it possible to create a default team at collection level (rather
>   than project level) and assign users to it?

No, it's impossible. In Azure DevOps, we provide **collection-project-team** structure.

[image]

**Within a project, you can add teams**

You could take a look at our official doc here-- [About projects and scaling your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) and then decide if you need to create multiple projects or teams in your  scenario.

---

As the above doc mentioned, we would suggest you handle a single project. Can a user account belong to more than one team?

Yes. When you add user accounts to a project, you can add them as members of the project, or you can add them to one or more teams added to the project.

Besides, you are also be able to structure hierarchical teams. Although there's no concept of subteams, you can create teams whose area paths are under another team, which effectively creates a hierarchy of teams. To learn more, see [Add another team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

Comment: Thanks. In our case, we have 35+ applications (windows/web/batch/services/components) and these are categorized into 5 collection (collection represent an business service). So we have 5-7 projects in each collection. As we have a dozen of permanent developers who works across all project. So the initial idea was to create a team with 12 members then assign this team as default all project. Post this, we can customize further to remove members if required.

Comment: If I get it correct, according to you, this requirement is not possible. If I am correct in my assumption, can you please provide any advise on how to tackle this requirement around team in more efficient way rather than adding individual members in every project

Comment: @Nair Correct, what you are looking for is not available currently.  According to your description, seems you have some users work not even across team projects but also collections in your company. For this kind of  scenario, I can not find a good way. Since every collection owe a corresponding database, it's not possible to manage/share info across separate database. I'm afraid, adding individual members in every project  is the only choice.  Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: That's OK. Thank you for the consistent support. I hope, if this kind of requirement is usual then there might be a solution on its way. By the way database/collections are under a single sql server instance. This might give further possibility to share server level security across collections. Thanks for you time :)

Comment: @Nair Thanks for your kindly response. To be honest, it's not a common situation. You could file a feature request (suggest a feature) in this  link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea. Our PM will review any suggestion. Moreover, if  my reply helped and you do not have any other concern. Appreciate for *marking it as an answer*  which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 0):

afaik it is not possible to create teams on collection level. you could, for example, create an Active Directory Group and use/reuse it in your projects.

Comment: Thanks, the idea was to follow a AD style grouping. However, this is not supported. Not sure whether it is unique in my case specifically on how members work between projects.

Comment: Have you connected your AD with DevOps like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops and after that, you should be able to add groups: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-azure-active-directory-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page